Probability of decreasing function of a random variable
I am confused with the following problem. Assume I have a general (not necessarily continuous)random variable $X$. Let's $g()$ be a general, not necessarily continuous but strictly increasing function. Do we always have
$$
P(X < a) = P(g(X) < g(a))
$$
?

Hint: remember the definition of strictly increasing function. Does it depend on continuity?

Strictly increasing functions have to be continuous except  at most countably many points on any finite interval.

yes, it's always true.

If g is strictly increasing, then the two conditions $X<a$ and $g(X)<g(a)$ are equivalent (i.e., they define exactly the same set), so the probabilities are the same.

Hint: Think of right continuous staircase functions. If $g$ jumps at $b < a$ then what is the set $\{g(X)<g(a)\}$? Is it equal to $\{ X <a \}$?

Since there is a downvote, I had to reread the question. Perhaps the OP means $g$ is still strictly increasing? Or the downvoter spot some mistakes? Please be civilized and point out the mistake :)

It is not me who downvoted, but the question explicitly says about strictly increasing functions

...but I see that the punctuation in the question is not very clear

Alright, I'm not a native speaker so I thought the OP meant not necessarily continuous + not necessarily strictly increasing...

Fixed your -1 :)

You're a saint Masi ^^. I'll wait until the OP found this comment helpful or not. If not I will delete it.

$g()$ it is strictly increasing but not necessarily continuous. I edited.

Dear LNT, could you, please, clarify?

Clarify what? The question you asked was just the definition of an strictly increasing function: If $a<b$ iff $g(a)<g(b)$. I thought you were confused when $g$ is NOT strictly increasing, then my comment gives you an example where your equality in probability above does not hold
